# Flutter api usage

Tags: json, api, flutter

I am very new to this business and cannot use api. No matter how much training content I look at, I run into errors when I try to try it myself. I cannot get out of this vicious circle. I leave the sample code snippets below. Please explain to me how I should think in this business. Thanks

User Model

```
class User{
  String userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  User({this.userId,this.id,this.title,this.body});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return User(
      userId: parsedJson["userId"],
      id: parsedJson["id"],
      title: parsedJson["title"],
      body: parsedJson["body"]
    );
  }
}
```

User Service

```
Future getUser() async{
  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"));
  final jsonDecode = json.decode(response.body);
  var user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode);
  return user;
  
}
```

Main Screen

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  User user = User();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUser().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        user = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: user == null
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("${user?.id}"),
                    Text("${user?.title}"),
                    Text("${user?.userId}"),
                    Text("${user?.body}"),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3Pxv.png)

Where am I making a mistake? Thanks for your explanatory answers.

Comment: `user` will never equal to null because you give it a default value of an empty User (with null variables). You should change it to `User? user;` so the `CircularProgressIndicator` will show up. Once you do that, see if it still shows all nulls or if it’s an endless progress indicator.

Comment: I did what you said and observed `CircularProgresIncicator` spinning infinitely

Comment: That would be why, it’s either not fetching the data, or it is and it’s failing. You should `print` the `response` and post it here.

Comment: `var response = await http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"));`  The `print(response);` that I wrote under this code; does not give any output

Comment: Wait a minute, are you hot reloading or hot restarting? `initState` won’t get called again with a hot reload.

Comment: I'm working with restart. I also stopped the application and run it again. I also noticed that the application does not enter any of the `final json decode ..` line in the getUser method. I discovered with BreakPoint

Comment: @oustW. `userId` should be int, not String. That's a type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it's throwing this exception:

```
 Unhandled Exception: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String?'
```

on this line in class `User`:

```
String userId;
```

`userId` in the json file is an int, not a String.

Change that line to:

```
int userId;
```

And it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure but it may work.

```
       Future<User> getUser() async{
  User user;
  http.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")).then({
     final jsonDecode = json.decode(response.body);
      User user = User.fromJson(jsonDecode);
      });
      return user;
    }
```

EDIT:
Define a bool

```
bool loading = true;
```

Call function loadSth

```
void initState() {
loadSth();
  super.initState();
}
```

Your function

```
loadSth(){
   getUser().then((value) {
user  = value;
      setState(() {
loading = false;

      });
}
```

And scaffold body wait until data is loaded;

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: loading == true
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Center(
              child: Column(............
```

Comment: I tried what they say Alperen, the result is the same. I also get an error in the first getUser method you shared.

Answer (score 0):

I'll iterate what @JediBurrel and @AlperenBaskaya have put.

1. The user will never be null coz you've initialized it with an empty User object.
2. The CircularProgressIndicator() should be used to show that something is happening therefore it should not be showing when a value is null.

Here's a sample code below to achieve what your usecase needs.

```
User user;
bool isLoading = false;


loadUser(){
 setState(() {
    isLoading = true;
  });
  getUser().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        user = value;
        isLoading = false;
      });
    });
}


void initState() {
loadUser();
  super.initState();
}

// In the Widget Build Have It Like This.....
Scaffold(
        body: isLoading
            ? CircularProgressIndicator()
            : Center(
              child: user == null
                   ? Text("There's No User Data to Display")
                   : Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                       children: [
                        Text("${user.id}"),
                        Text("${user.title}"),
                        Text("${user.userId}"),
                        Text("${user.body}"),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
      ),
    );
```